# Cakephp sort on field of 2nd level associated table

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

I seem to have a weird problem.
Using Cakephp2 I have 3 tables related like:

```
taxon->has genus_id

genus -> has family_id
```

Using the Taxon model I can correctly retreive all data as expected. Now I would like to sort on family. Therefore I've written the joins manually into the paginate array. If I add

```
'order' => 'Family.family desc'
```

to the paginate array directly, the sorting works as expected. But only as long as the params

```
sort:Family.family/direction:desc
```

are not part of the url. As soon as theses params are added to the url, the order part gets emptied. How can I avoid this behaviour and get the results correctly ordered?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the implementation of Paginator.validateSort. If sort parameters are passed, validate sort checks, if the model has the fields passed. This check is done for the model and for directly (1st level) related models only but not for models with deeper nested associations.
I solved the problem by modifying the validateSort method. I've added the (not very elegant) possibility to pass fields followed by an exclamation mark like 'Family.family!'. Such fields are added to the order array even if they fail the check.

Regards

Alex